# how to set protocol function not properly invoke in DataProvider class Alamofire function swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, alamofire, protocols

I need to set protocol function in Alamofire download function to track and observe progress fraction value. I have to tried to implement delegate function but its not properly executes giving error. I have one DataProvider class which has Alamofire function and then I am calling this in ViewController.

Errors getting on `init(webService: DataProvider = DataProvider())`:

```
'self' used before 'super.init' call
'super.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer
```

ViewController Code:

```
let webService: DataProvider

    init(webService: DataProvider = DataProvider()) {
        //super.init()
        self.webService = webService
        self.webService.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

extension DownloadViewController: MyWebServiceProtocol {
    func progress(_ fractionCompleted: Double) {
        print(fractionCompleted)
    }

    func downloadDidSucceed() {
        print("download")
    }


    func downloadDidFail(error: Error) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

DataProvider.Class

```
protocol MyWebServiceProtocol: class {
   func progress(_ fractionCompleted: Double)
   func downloadDidSucceed()
   func downloadDidFail(error: Error)
}

// in class
weak var delegate: MyWebServiceProtocol?

//Alamofire

Alamofire.download(
            url,
            method: .get,
            parameters: nil,
            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
            headers: nil,
            to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                //progress closure
                self.delegate?.progress(progress.fractionCompleted)

                print(progress.fractionCompleted)
            }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
                //here you able to access the DefaultDownloadResponse
                //result closure
                callback(DefaultDownloadResponse.response?.statusCode == 200, DefaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL?.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: ""))
                print(DefaultDownloadResponse)
                self.delegate?.downloadDidSucceed()
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `super.init()` before using self object so that properties of base class are initialized before using self.

Comment: In DataProvider.class `init()` already using. If I am going to use it again in `ViewController`  `super.init()`  error generates. `Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIViewController' `

Comment: Understood. can you make you initialiser as convenience initialiser as below, convenience init(webService: DataProvider = DataProvider()) {
        self.init()
        self.webService = webService
        self.webService.delegate = self
    }

Comment: Now on `fatalError` it gives me error `Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file /Users/macuser/Documents/XCodeWork/ABC/ABC/ViewControllers/DownloadViewController.swift `

Comment: Try this,  `var webService: DataProvider?
    
    convenience init(webService: DataProvider = DataProvider()) {
        self.init()
        self.webService = webService
        self.webService?.delegate = self
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }`

Comment: done that one. No error this time but not invoking  to `func progress(_ fractionCompleted: Double) { print(fractionCompleted) } ` even I set the breakpoint for it.

Comment: Actually this whole scenario confused me the reason behind this I am downloading files and webservices data. In viewController I am using all webservice callback functions and in `DataProvider class` Alamofire function ( request & download). And I am stuck in download design thing. Not getting any good tutorial or information regarding this.